# How to use Argument Parse in Google Colabs

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

The Following Code of mine produces some error

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
args = ap.parse_args()
```

But Even Without adding any argument it still produces below error

```
  /usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py in exit(self, status, message)
  2502         if message:
  2503             self._print_message(message, _sys.stderr)
  -> 2504         _sys.exit(status)
  2505 
  2506     def error(self, message):`enter code here`
  SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: Please add some detail. Code only questions are very broad and not many people can help you that way.

Comment: If you are getting an error message, include the error message in the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want this code to run on Google Collab with no error, you should add an additionnal argument option to your `ArgumentParser`:

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream 
from imutils.video import FPS 
import argparse 
import imutils 
import time 
import cv2 

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", type=str,help="path to input video file",) 
ap.add_argument("-t", "--tracker", required=False,type=str, default="kcf", help="OpenCV object tracker type") 
ap.add_argument("-f", "--file", required=False) 

args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```