# SystemExit: 2 Unrecognized Arguments in python google colab

Tags: python, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

```
1 **import** os
2 **import** argparse
3 **from** argparse **import** ArgumentParser
4 **import** numpy as np
5 **def** convert_to_numpy(input,H,W):
6    image = input[:,:,padsize:H-padsize,padsize:W-padsize].clone()
7    input_numpy = image[:,:,:H,:W].clone().cpu().numpy().reshape(3,H-padsize*2,W-padsize*2).transpose(1,2,0)
8   **for** i in range(3):
9        input_numpy[:,:,i] = input_numpy[:,:,i] * std[i] + mean[i]
10        return  input_numpy
11      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
12 parser.add_argument("--dataset_name", type=str, default="usrImg", help="name of folder")
13 opt = parser.parse_args()
```

i am running this code and getting error at
parser.add_argument("--dataset_name", type=str, default="usrImg", help="name of folder")

**Error is:**
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] Datasetname
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

How can I solve it?

**Computer Environment:**

```
**->**Windows 10 64-bit
**->**Python version 3.6.9
**->**Working on Google Colaboratory
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, how exactly are you running this code and where is the -f parameter coming from?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I want to give parameters of image but it gives me error unrecognized arguments.I cannot understand how to give path or folder name in line 12

Comment: https://github.com/ryo-abiko/GCNet.git this is link from where i get this code

Comment: You didn't answer my question, in the repo there is a clear usage example, why aren't you following it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `opt = parser.parse_args(args=[])`.

Comment: Could you explain why the solution you provided can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution provided by this other stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232066/how-do-i-fix-it-with-colab) and it works.